# STOMP selectors Python For ActiveMq

Tags: python

I am trying to get this script to work, I need to filter a Stompy subscription on the custom header field "Test".

But every time i try, it doesn't get received, I can see the message in the queue fine, but the subscriber never takes it off the queue. When I remove the selector statement in the subscriber, I can receive the message.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from stompy.simple import Client
import json

Dict_Message = dict()
Dict_Message["Test1"] = "CONDOR"

stomp = Client("localhost", 61613)
stomp.connect("producer", "pass")
stomp.put(json.dumps(Dict_Message), destination="/queue/test",conf={'Test':'Test123'})
stomp.disconnect()

stomp = Client("localhost", 61613)
stomp.connect("consumer", "pass")
stomp.subscribe("/queue/test",conf={'selector' : "'Test' = 'Test123'"})
#stomp.subscribe("/queue/test")
message = stomp.get()

print message.headers
New_Dict = json.loads(message.body)
print New_Dict
stomp.ack(message)
stomp.unsubscribe("/queue/test")
stomp.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the '' in the name of field in the selector. The syntax in the selector is like SQL, it is not like JSON.

```
stomp.subscribe("/queue/test",conf={'selector' : "Test = 'Test123'"})
```

In fact, I don´t use tiles at all in the text of the selector.